# Problems to save pdf files from Dropbox

Tags: pdf, dropbox

I'm trying to download one list of scientific papers in pdf format from dropbox. But the download process stops at 100% (without conclude). The interesting point is that I can open my file directly on the browser, or even in a pdf reader. But I'm not able to save it.

One example of the problem:

1. Ubuntu version: 12.10
2. From: Dropbox
3. Size of the file:374kb
4. Name of the file: Packalén, Mehtätalo, Maltamo - 2011 - ALS based estimation
   of plot volume and site index in a eucalyptus plantation with a
   nonlinear mixed effect model that accounts for the clone effect.pdf
5. Destination: /home/user/Downloaded/

Some suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using firefox.

Comment: Does this happen only in dropbox and only by using firefox? Is the file in a private or in a public Dropbox Folder?

Comment: I have noticed just during those dropbox files download. It is my own dropbox section.

Comment: Maybe try shortening the file name? 190 characters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Douggro hit the bull's eye! Some pdf's were uploaded from a Windows computer with more than 190 characters. Because of that, the Dropbox in Ubuntu couldn't sync those files. To solve the problem, I edited the file names inside Dropbox web and then, ok! The synchronization goes right!

I had similar problems to sync my Mendeley account. In that case, the solution was a little more complicated, because Mendeley does not support web edition. In that case, I had to change in my windows computer the names and after sync, the Mendeley account could update the file in Ubuntu computer.